# Get start time of available time slots

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp, logic

I want to fetch non-overlapped time slots with a certain duration.
Here is my work.

```
function detect_not_overlap($date, $worker_id, $duration) {
    $available_slots = [];

    $start_time = strtotime('09:00:00');
    $end_time = strtotime('17:00:00');

    while ($start_time <= $end_time - $duration * 3600) {
        $start = date('H:i:s', $start_time);
        $start_timestamp = strtotime($start);
    
        $end = date('H:i:s', $start_time + $duration * 3600);
        $end_timestamp = strtotime($end);
        
        $db = new DatabaseManager();
        $apDAO = new AppointmentDAO($db);
        $count_existing_slots = $apDAO->getOverlappedCount($start_timestamp,$end_timestamp, $date, $worker_id);
        if ($count_existing_slots == 0 || $count_existing_slots == null) {
            $available_slots[] = date('H:i:s', $start_time);
    
        }

        $start_time += 30 * 60;
        //$start_time = strtotime('+30 minutes', $start_time);
    }

    return $available_slots;
}
```

the code seems correct to me but it does not provide correct results.
Here is the function I used to fetch database data.

```
 public function getOverlappedCount($start_time, $end_time, $date, $worker_id) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM appointment WHERE end_time > :start_time AND start_time < :end_time AND date = :date AND worker_id = :worker_id");
        $stmt->bindValue(":start_time", $start_time);
        $stmt->bindValue(":end_time", $end_time);
        $stmt->bindValue(":date", $date);
        $stmt->bindValue(":worker_id", $worker_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        return $count;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        $this->db->closeConnection();
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out where the fault is, can you offer any assistance to solve this?
[image: Here is the existing slots in the table]

[image: Here is the results]
Here when the start time is 11 and the end time is 12 the the existing time 10.30 to 11.30 should be overlapped but my program shows it is not overlapped by count=0.

Comment: Show some sample data and actual and expected results that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: It looks like you have fixed time slots of 30 minutes. Why then use the `$duration` variable? That should always have a value of 0.5 or your code will not work properly. Also, the lines `$db = new DatabaseManager();` and `$apDAO = new AppointmentDAO($db);` should probably be moved above the loop, and the closing of the connection should be below the loop, not in the `getOverlappedCount()` function.

Comment: Duration for calculating the end time of the appointment and checking whether the time slot clashes.

Comment: start time only increments by 30 minutes.

Comment: OK, I get it, a time slot can only start each half hour, but it can end at any time.

Comment: The way you manipulate time doesn't seem correct. You feed the `getOverlappedCount()` function with absolute time stamps. See: https://3v4l.org/EoonX

Comment: Do you know the correct time format

Comment: Not really. I can only go by the image of your database table. There start_time contains a time, not a date, so I assume that `$start_time` should also contain a time, and not an absolute date-time timestamp.

Comment: Is the logic of the code correct?

Comment: I can't test it, but the logic itself does seem correct to me. Fix the arguments you give to the `getOverlappedCount()` function, and it could work.